# Coding in javascript: a mix of standard javascript and jquery? any issues?

Tags: javascript, jquery

are there any problems mixing my code with standard javascript and jquery? Will things conflict? Would I be unable to use standard javascript within jquery calls?

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript. JavaScript is the language, jQuery is a library. You cannot use jQuery without writing JavaScript. If you mean whether you should use the normal DOM interface if you use jQuery, then the answer is *it depends*. Use jQuery where it simplifies your code, but don't over-use it. There won't be any conflicts though. The most important thing is to be consistent.

Comment: @FelixKling: Amen. (I ran out of comment votes)

Comment: Hm, writing jQuery without writing JavaScript... CHALLENGE ACCEPTED `:p`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### jQuery is framework for JavaScript

This means that if you use jQuery, you use JavaScript at the same time.

So **no**, there will be no issues if you put JavaScript inside the code that already uses jQuery, because you add nothing new / conflicting. Because you already are using JavaScript within your code.

Answer (score 1):

The only issues you will find is if your code overwrites the base prototypes.  Otherwise your code will work fine with javascript libraries and frameworks including JQuery.

Comment: yes, he is asking if his specific javascript can be added and used with JQuery. There are some things that will break most javascript libraries.  For example overwriting the push and pop functions so they are custom can wreak havoc on most libraries.

Comment: Or overwriting `window`, or `document`, or `jQuery`, or `Array`, but still saying "they play very nice" is **far** from being true. jQuery does not "play" with JavaScript nicely, it **is** JavaScript. It is like extension based on JavaScript, written on top of it. If you use some other JavaScript, you can still break existing JavaScript, but it is true with most programming languages. **Anyway, how would you like to write code that uses jQuery, but does not use "standard JavaScript"? Please exaplain.**

Comment: maybe I misread the question, he's asking if "his code" will mix with "standard javascript and jquery".  I've tried to add jquery to others websites and been burned because they had a programmer from hell overwritting all the prototypes.  I'll try and be more verbose so I'm not as ambiguous and confusing in the future.

Comment: Ok, I have experienced similar things in the past. However overwriting prototypes is not always wrong - I believe wonderful Mootools framework is based on that. And Mootools adds some extra layer for JavaScript code. But the case you are describing is worth mentioning when someone wants to play with prototypes without knowing the consequences.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does a good job of keeping itself compartmentalized within the `jQuery` (or `$`) object, so it plays well with existing JavaScript, and even with other JS APIs. The only thing I can think of that you should really look out for is if you use `$` elsewhere (for example, if you use PrototypeJS). In that case, you can use jQuery's [noConflict](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

Answer (score 0):

No there wont be any problems.

JQuery is just JavaScript written by other developers available to you through an API. Therefore, JavaScript inside JQuery is just JavaScript inside JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some problems with using onclick="javascript......" handlers at the same time as using jQuery handlers.

I would suggest if using jQuery to tend toward using it's handler system rather than the html versions.